# Earth Engine - Exporting image after object based methods/analysis

Tags: google-earth-engine

I performed object-based methods to calculate a mean (zonal statistics) for connected pixels adapted from this guide: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_objects#label_objects

Here is a sample of the code I used the get that final layer:

```
var objectBased = changeLayer.select([0], ['change'])

var objectId = objectBased.connectedComponents({
  connectedness: ee.Kernel.plus(2),
  maxSize: 1024});
  
Map.addLayer(objectId.randomVisualizer(), null, 'Objects', false);

test = changeLayerClass.addBands(objectId.select('labels'));

var meanClass = test.reduceConnectedComponents({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  labelBand: 'labels',
  maxSize: 1024
});

Map.addLayer(meanClass, {min:3, max:5, palette:['red', 'yellow']}, 'Mean Class', false)

var disturbanceType = meanClass.select(0).gte(4)

Map.addLayer(disturbanceType, {palette:['red', 'yellow']}, 'disturbance')

Export.image.toAsset({
  image: disturbanceType,
  description: 'objectBasedDisturbanceType',
  scale: 10,
  region: geometry,
  maxPixels:300000000
});
```

I don't encounter a problem when running the analysis, but when I export the end image. The objects that are large are not exported as the other smaller objects.

[image: Object.Id layer]
Result of the object-based analysis

[image: Result of the object-based analysis]

Result when visualizing the exported image
[image: Result when visualizing the exported image]

How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The large objects exceed the `maxsize` you're specified when the data is processed at a scale of 10m.  You don't have this problem while viewing, because you're not viewing it at the full 10m (but you will, if you zoom in).

Your best bet is to export the image at something close to the scale at which you're viewing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way to force those big objects to split in two so I can export them? if my goal is to ultimately keep that 10m scale.

Comment: Well, you could manually clip them in 1/2 by drawing a geometry on top of them and erasing 1/2 the object, but there's probably a better answer if you can explain the bigger picture of what you're doing and why you're doing it this way.

Comment: I am working on typing forest change across Canada. So red means fire change and yellow harvest change. Manually clipping is not really an option here since I am looking to do this "unsupervised" in part due to the extent of area I am looking at. Maybe object-based typing is not the solution in this case..